# React Hooks. Parent component not rerendering to execute conditional statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to rerender Apps.js to read the updated conditional statement from Start.js component to a div. Currently, I have the global state management pattern and so when I go to click on a button from the Start component, it does not trigger App.js to re-render. 
App.js

````
import { GlobalContext } from "./context/GlobalState";
import Start from "./components/start";
import "./App.css";
import { GlobalProvider } from "./context/GlobalState";

function App() {
  const {
    showStartPage,
    test,
    tester
    // header,
    // showGroup,
    // currentQuestion,
    // direction,
    // handleNextQuestion,
    // handlePreviousQuestion,
    // completion,
  } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const [show, setShow] = useState(showStartPage);
  // let showPage = false

  useEffect(() => {
    // setShow(showStartPage)
    //
    // return showStartPage => {};
    //   tester();

    setShow(showStartPage);
    if (!showStartPage) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
    //   // const survey = showStartPage ? <Start /> : null;
    console.log("from APP.js", show);
  }, [showStartPage, show]);

  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
      {showStartPage ? (
        <Start />
      ) : (
        <>
          <div>Survey Questions will Go Here {test}</div>
        </>
      )}
    </GlobalProvider>
  );
}

export default App.js```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your `App` component with `GlobalProvider` in `index.js`, not in  `App.js`

```
ReactDOM.render(<GlobalProvider><App /></GlobalProvider>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Updates to context values will cause re-render to the only components that are rendered within the Context Provider.

Comment: Thank you sir! 